Best structure for precompiling Julia script into a sysimage
I have a Julia script running a computational intensive workflow. For performance reasons I would like to create a sysimage of this to reduce runtime. I've explored using PackageCompiler. From what I understand I would need to create a project, bundle my script into package and then include that package in the precompile_warmup script of my project. This all seems very unnecessary. Is there an easier way of accomplishing this using PackageCompiler?

No, but can you describe in your question what specifically you are trying to do? What is the computationally intensive workflow that you think a sysimage will help speed up? Do you have any benchmarks that show where the code is too slow for your workflow? A PackageCompiler-generated sysimage will reduce startup and compilation time, but outside of those will have little impact on the execution time of well-designed Julia code, so perhaps there are lower-hanging fruits to pick first.
